# Can we overload operators for built-in types like int or float?

Tags: c++, overloading

Can we declare a function like this in C++:

```
int operator + (int , int);
```

Comment: You cannot overload operators for built-in types.

Comment: Your questions body seems to have nothing to do with the title. What are you asking?

Comment: i think the argument must be objects,if you are allowed to overload int type then overall arithmetic operation will be a chaos

Comment: However, you can define `expression templates` to achieve the same effect, see e.g. my example here: **[Can we inherit from Qt containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929735/can-we-inherit-from-qt-containers/17929800#17929800)**

Comment: "Named operators" is [another advanced idiom](https://github.com/klmr/named-operator) that you might employ to get "close": `x = a <plus> b` could be "overloaded"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot redefine a built-in operator.  Operator overloading
is designed to allow you to extend the language, not to change
it.  At least one of the parameters of an overloaded operator
must be a user defined type (class or enum type) or a reference
to a user defined type.

Answer (score 13):

Yes: You can pass ints and floats into overloaded functions

No: You cannot overload/override the operators for built in types when the built-in types are on both sides of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

No we cannot overload integer or float types because overloading means to change the working of existing operators or make them to work with objects int is single member not an object.