# How can I re-define + operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I would like to re-define

> +

operator.

So, I make a simple code like below code.

```
int operator+(const int &a, const int &b)
{
    int temp = a-b;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 5;
    cout << a+b << endl;
}
```

I can re-define with Class type... But I don't want to use Class.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941531/can-we-overload-operators-for-built-in-types-like-int-or-float

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define the operators for plain old data types like `int`.

You *could* build your own `int` class (`my_int`, say) and include the line `#define int my_int`. But this would be *extremely* pernicious and wouldn't work with compile-time evaluated literal expressions.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot redefine operator for int (or any other built in type). 
If you say, what do you want to do, we might find some solution.

Comment: I'd like to re-define ^ operator.
If an user enters '2^4', the system gives '16' the user.
But, a same error occurred....

Comment: @InhwanRyu why would you do that? What problem do you want to solve with it? Still you cannot redefine operators of built in types

Comment: It need the ^ operator overloading to input and solve an quadratic equation.

Comment: @InhwanRyu you want to use it as a pow operator? Why not use the `pow` function istead?

Comment: I know the pow function.... I think I have to use a substring function. and then use pow function...

Comment: @InhwanRyu Anyway you would need to convert string to int or double. Even if `^` was redefined