# Why is it called operator overloading?

Tags: c++, c++11

If the following class, `Foo`, is defined. It is said it **overloads** the *unary ampersand* (`&`) operator:

```
class Foo {
public:
   Foo* operator&() { return nullptr; }
};
```

I think in this case, (reglardless of the fact that you can get the address of such an object by means of `std::addressof()` and other idiomatic tricks) there is no way to access/choose the original unary ampersand operator that returns the address of the object called on, am I wrong?

By *overloading* however, I understand that there is a set of functions of which one will be selected at compile-time based on some criteria. But this thinking doesn't seem to match the scenario above.

Why is it then called *overloading* and not something else like *redefining* or *replacing*?

Comment: @Zereges I am not asking about getting the address of the object, but calling the original `&` operator.

Comment: With `Foo : public Bar`, `Bar* x = new Foo`, `&*x` will not use the overloaded operator; it is not overridden. You need to access it through a type that includes it, so it’s overloaded.

Comment: @Ryan interesting observation

Comment: Sorry, on second thought, that’s misleading. The terminology is straightforward: it’s the operator itself – `&`, not `Foo::operator&` – that’s overloaded to do something different on a particular type. `int + int`, `string + string`, etc. are overloads of `+`. If you think of it as `ampersand(…)` and `plus(…, …)`, it’s the same as function overloading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
int x;
Foo y;
&x; // built-in functionality
&y; // y.operator&();
```

We have two variables of different types. We apply the same `&` operator to both of them. For `x` it uses the built-in address-of operator whereas for `y` it calls your user-defined function.

That's exactly what you're describing as *overloading*: There are multiple functions (well, one of them is the built-in functionality, not really a "function") and they're selected based on the type of the operand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redefine a function or operator in C++, you can add only new use to it, defining new set of arguments. That's why it called overloading instead of redefining.

When you overload operator as a member of class you

1) defined it with first argument supposed to be an instance of that class

2) gave it access to all members of that class.

There are still definitions of operator& with different arguments and you have a non-zero chance to create situation where use of operator would be ambigous.

Comment: That is, you said it: *you can add only new use to it, defining new set of arguments. That's why it called overloading instead of redefining.* It is about extending, not replacing. [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17941791/8012646).