# C++ Operator Overloading??? Isn't it more like override?

Tags: c++, operators, overriding, overloading

In C++, why is operator overloading called "overloading"?

To me, this seems more like "override."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44101287

Comment: @imm you should pick an answer below (i.e. mark as solution) if it was the one that helped you fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not changing the meaning of +, -, *, / etc. with respect to the fundamental datatypes. You can't change what those means for char, short, int, float, etc. Therefore, you're not truly overriding anything.

You are instead expanding the meaning of them to new contexts, which seems to fit with the term "overloading": you've loaded the symbols onto new meanings they did not previously have.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty subjective, and not easy to answer in specific terms.

But generally we use "override" to mean "replacing the behaviour of a function with another behaviour", as in when you have a polymorphic class hierarchy, and a call to a function whose various implementations are `virtual` can result in totally different behaviour. Certainly that's what the standard means by the term.

Isn't this also what happens with overloading? Kind of. But usually when you overload a function, you do so to give it different parameter lists, but would still expect each implementation to perform the same job. It doesn't *have* to, but one expects it to.

Similarly with overloaded operators, if you're overloading say `operator+` then generally we expect that it actually still just does the normal, conventional "addition" logic — but *overloaded* so that it can take an argument of your new class type, instead of the existing overloads that take built-in types.

In practice, that breaks down a bit, because even the standard library makes `operator<<` mean something completely different (among other examples).

Still, the actual task of creating these new operators *is* accomplished by what the language considers to be function *overloading* (particularly as no `virtual` calls are involved at all).

In short, you're arguably not entirely wrong, but it's pretty arbitrary and this is what we ended up with.

Comment: I totally understand. Thank you.

Comment: @imm Best I can do!