# C++ competitive programming : Simplifying expressions under modulo N

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, modulo

There are many problems on codechef that require doing operations modulo some number
[like in this one](https://www.codechef.com/JUNE17/problems/SUMQ/). I happen to write `% MOD` for each arithmetic operator used for eg -

`ans += (((sumX*sumZ) % MOD + (sumX + sumZ) % MOD) % MOD * Y) % MOD;`

Now is there any way in c++ to do it implicitly?

Though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941531/can-we-overload-operators-for-built-in-types-like-int-or-float) says we cannot overload arithmetic operators for built-in types, but still is their any way to make it possible to write 
it like `ans += (sumX*sumZ + (sumX + sumZ)) * Y`
 ?

Comment: Sure, make your own type and overload all the operators to have this behavior.

Comment: You could write a custom type like "my int" and use that. However, some amount of boilerplate is often needed and replacing it with "clever" operator overriding could often be quite dnagerous

Comment: So are you suggesting not to use operator overloading? Is there any other way to simplify writing the above expression?

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh: The problem is not in operator overloading itself. That's just a fancy way of naming your functions. The danger is in correctly implementing them. You generally can't assume the underlying C++ type works same as naive math. Say you use `unsigned`, then `a*b %c` is really `a * b % ~0U % c`. And signed `int` has Undefined Behavior on overflow.

Comment: @MSalters But assuming the number MOD is less than ~0u, then there won't be any overflow, right ?

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh: There is, in intermediaries. Assume (to make the math easy) that ~0u is 255, and MOD=254. Now 253+253 MOD 254 = 252. But there's an overflow first: 253 + 253 = 250, and 250 MOD 254 is 250.

Comment: But that is still the case with using `(sumX*sumZ) % MOD` too, so we'd anyway have to choose a larger datatype like `long long int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @StoryTeller and @MSalters, I finally made this snippet that I can use for solving coding problems-

```
#define ll long long int
#define MOD 1000000007

template<typename Number, Number m>
class modNum
{
private:
    Number a;
public:
    // overloading '<<'
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, modNum const & num) {
          return os << num.a;
      }
    modNum(Number a) : a(a % m) {}

    Number get() const { return a; }

    modNum operator+= (modNum b){ a = (a + b.get()) % m; return a; }
    modNum operator*= (modNum b){ a = (a * b.get()) % m; return a; }
    modNum operator/= (modNum b){ a = (a / b.get()) % m; return a; }
    modNum operator-= (modNum b){ a = (a - b.get()) % m; return a; }
    modNum operator + (modNum b){modNum t = (a + b.get()) % m; return t;}
    modNum operator * (modNum b){modNum t = (a * b.get()) % m; return t;}
    modNum operator / (modNum b){modNum t = (a / b.get()) % m; return t;}
    modNum operator - (modNum b){modNum t = (a - b.get()) % m; return t;}

};
typedef modNum<ll, MOD> num_t;
//testing the code-
int int_max = 2147483647;
int sqroot_max = sqrt(int_max);

int main()
{
    num_t sumX(sqroot_max),sumZ(sqroot_max),Y(sqroot_max);
    cout<<(sumX*sumZ + sumX+sumZ)*Y;
    // (((sumX*sumZ) % MOD + (sumX + sumZ) % MOD) % MOD * Y) % MOD;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The division is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a small wrapper that represents numbers modulo a quantity.

```
template<typename Number, Number Width>
class ModuloArithmetic
{
  Number n;
public:
  ModuloArithmetic(Number n) : n(n % Width) {}
  Number get() const { return n; }

  ModuloArithmetic& operator+= (ModuloArithmetic other)
  { n = (n + other.get()) % Width; return *this; }

  // Other modifying operators 
};

template<typename Number, Number Width>
ModuloArithmetic<Number, Width> operator+(
  ModuloArithmetic<Number, Width> lhs,
  ModuloArithmetic<Number, Width> rhs) {
  return lhs.get() + rhs.get();
}

// And so forth for the other arithmetic operations.
```

The operators always deal in the wrapper class itself. So even though the operators don't explicitly preform a modulo operation, it will be done on return when "boxing" the result.

Then it's a simple matter of defining all your number in terms of it:

```
using num_t = ModuloArithmetic<int, MOD>;
num_t sumX, sumZ;
```

Comment: And this already has a problem when `MOD > INT_MAX/2`. Addition may overflow the intermediate result.

Comment: @MSalters - True, but that's a risk without the wrapper as well. I would like to think the OP is in the realm of sensible widths. Although adding static_asserts on Width compared to numeric_limits may be feasible.