# Assignment Operator Overloading In C++(using pointer objects)

Tags: c++, pointers, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a simple class that has an integer pointer, assignment operator overloading and... . Then i declare two pointer objects(t1 and t2) and assigning t2 to t1.
the problem is that this assignment is a default copy assignment operator and i don't want that.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
    int *x;
public:
    Test(int val =0 ):x{new int(val)}{}
    void setX(int val){*x = val;}
    void print(){cout<< "OUTPUT:"<< *x<<endl;}
    ~Test(){delete x;}

    Test* operator = (const Test* rhs){
        if(this != rhs)
            *x = *(rhs->x);
        return this;
    }
};
 int main(){
    Test* t1 = new  Test(5);
    Test* t2 = new Test(10);
    t1 = t2;

    t1->setX(1555);
    t1->print();
    t2->print();

 }
```

the code below works well but i need objects to be pointers(in fact i working on a project that  objects are template pointers and i cross the same problem(default copy assignment operator is invoked.)) :

```
class Test{
    int *x;
public:
    Test(int val =0 ):x{new int(val)}{}
    void setX(int val){*x = val;}
    void print(){cout<< "OUTPUT:"<< *x<<endl;}
    ~Test(){delete x;}

    Test& operator = (const Test& rhs){
        if(this != &rhs)
            *x = *rhs.x;
        return *this;
    }
};
 int main(){
    Test t1(5);
    Test t2(10);
    t1 = t2;

    t1.setX(1555);
    t1.print();
    t2.print();

 }
```

Comment: It would be so much simpler to kill pointers entirely and use shared_ptr<> instead.

Comment: You are missing the `Test` copy constructor: `Test(const Test&)`

Comment: You can't overload anything for fundamental types. Use "normal" assignment – `*p1 = *p2;` – and don't try to invent your own unconventional semantics.

Comment: Simply, you can't.
It is not supported. [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48454551/c-pointer-assignment-operator-overloadnot-just-object-assignment-but-pointer)

Comment: [Here is how you would write this code in proper C++.](https://godbolt.org/z/Wru_AQ) No pointers needed at all.