# c++ how to send object pointer to function (sort list of pointers )

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, operator-overloading, operators

I am using

```
std::list<Employee*> Employees;
```

Employee is a class 
so my proplem is that i need to sort list, and for doing that i must define operator < 
but i don't know how to define the operator to take Employee* object
this is my define

```
bool operator <(const Employee *_employee) const { return (id < _employee->id); }
```

but its work only for `Employee < Employee*` but i need the operator to work on `Employee* < Employee*`

or if there anther solution for sorting the list well help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to provide `operator<`, and [you can't, with both arguments being pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941531/can-we-overload-operators-for-built-in-types-like-int-or-float) (they are considered as a built-in type, and there already is a built-in `operator<` that the language won't let you change).

Use the [second `std::list::sort` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) instead, with a custom comparison function
(a non-member function with two parameters):

```
bool employee_ptr_cmp(Employee const* lhs, Employee const* rhs) { ... }
...
Employees.sort(employee_ptr_cmp);
```

or a lambda function defined in-place:

```
Employees.sort([](Employee const* lhs, Employee const* rhs) { ... });
```

---

<sub>You should understand what your code above does. It allows you to compare `const Employee` with `Employee const*`, in this order. They're not both pointers. It is also preferred to [overload binary operators as non-member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function).</sub>